# Problem with reputation system and duplicates

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I think there might be a problem with duplicates and the reputation system. I have been on SE for quite a while. I happened to change my account a while ago; I am not new here.

Reputation is supposed to measure the quality of the contributions of a user and their level of expertise.

The problem is that normal people, with a decent level of expertise but not able to make very technical/difficult answers, that arrive on Stack Exchange nowadays have it enormously more difficult to gain reputation than it was 10 years ago. This is important if we take into account that reputation earns you privileges on this platform. Because a question will be marked as a duplicate when it is, well, a duplicate, and usually downvoted, **these people are even *losing* reputation *for asking the same question as some old user from 2010, who was awarded thousands of upvotes.***

Is this understandable by the argument of those old people having less available information at that time on the internet and Stack Exchange, and the new ones being "punished" by the fact that they haven't looked well enough? Maybe, but at the same time, back in the day those old users could ask without looking up anything on their own, and earn thousands of upvotes  by asking pretty simple questions. Also, even if new users don't ask any duplicates, they will have a harder time earning points. This is because simple questions are easier to answer correctly by newbies. Some newbies will have almost no rep, and some people have a huge amount, depending on luck.

Obviously, I am not criticizing these old users, they came in the right time and got lucky. But, I thought it might be good to point out that rep seems to be too much based on the luck you have in being the first to ask, even if the question is completely simple and maybe is just out there on the documentation/internet or whatever.

Maybe, something like [this](https://StackRating.com) could be more informative of someone's skill:

Comment: And your point is?

Comment: Well - if you had found that question and the answers worked, you wouldn't have asked the question?

Comment: Rep supposedly being a tangible way of measuring someone expertise being based on luck. I am not criticizing the situation which is obviously normal, that at the begining it was easier to find an unanswered question. But the fact that reputation tries to show your ability, by evaluating something that might not reflect it.

Comment: We're not optimizing for fair rep to everyone. This is not a game. It is a body of knowledge. If you open a dictionary you would be pretty annoyed if you find the definition of the same word spread across the book. Same here, duplicates are not always useful, unless it is a good sign post to the canonical question.

Comment: Yes I agree rene, I have not got any problems with duplicates. I was talking about the usefulness of reputation right now and what is it really trying to show. If it is skill, maybe is lacking/not being the most useful it could be

Comment: Reputation shows that *others* deemed my content to be useful. It is not my fault they clicked upvote. And it is not my fault users tend to take those Fake Internet Points so serious.

Comment: The problem with those fake internet points is that they earn you basic SE functionalities

Comment: The irony is that I remember a meta post exactly like this one 8-10yrs ago. The grass is always greener. There are still an uncountable number of good unasked questions. The question is whether you can find or ask them.

Comment: There are many, many corners of Stack Overflow, outside the main tags filled with beginner questions, where it just requires hard work and very little expertise to gain reputation. They won't come easy, but they will, and you might get lucky. More importantly, you will learn a lot in the process. For instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc) is in need of a ***comprehensive*** answer.

Answer (score 13):

You need a different mind-set.

If your motivation is: *How can I earn reputation?* then you're in for a rough ride. That is ultimately not the goal of the Stack Exchange Network.

Sites here try to be a body of knowledge for generations to come. The community members on their respective sites strive to curate the content on a specific topic in the form of Questions and Answers. The community is driven by quality, not quantity.

Given the above goal it is inevitable that as time progresses more and more questions are already asked. And by the virtue of quality it is not useful to have two or more versions of the same question. Re-asking the exact same question that would render the exact same answer is not a useful addition to the body of knowledge, as a matter of fact, it dilutes the knowledge. That is not useful. Content that is not useful gets downvoted so future visitors know the content is sub-par.

This doesn't mean you can never re-ask an old question. But you need to bring in a new viewpoint, a fresh insight, a twist, a unique context that warrants new and different answers. Yes, that does require more effort from the asker but if done right, those questions can be extremely useful.

Now let's assume you didn't explode in anger while reading this far but you're still not convinced reputation is a side-effect of useful content, you can take matters in your own hand. If you really want rep without the burden of posting awesome content you can suggest edits to existing posts, both new and old. If your edits gets approved by reviewers you earn 2 reputation. Do that 7 times and you earn the vote-up privilege. 25 times and you can comment everywhere. You get the idea.

tl;dr: There is no problem with reputation and duplicates, at least not in how you described the problem. Reputation is a number that indicates how useful all the content contributed by a user is. Posting content is a way to gain trust but it is not the only way.

There is nothing unfair about the system and no-one is punished due to that. Unless you post content that is not useful. Your content is punished in that case and rightfully so.

Comment: Yeah I do not care so much about rep. And I do not anger, I asked this question to hear you guys! Mainly because if the system has been for so long, it is because of something I am missing. I just wanted to know if this is something that people were concerned about and care about. There is always room for improvement in the user experience so I find these discussions ultimately useful, even if the decision is to keep it as it is. I find the reputation system *perfectly good enough* and I love SE, only that I see a slight room for improvement but I still prefer this system to some others.

Answer (score 7):

New technologies appear all the time. The Swift programming language has only been around [since 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) so nobody's going to have questions from 2010.

Existing programming languages also gain new features. There aren't going to be questions or answers about [C++ lambda capture](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0409r2.html) before 2017

I mention these because Stack Overflow is the largest site and is often cited as the one that's hardest to earn rep on because of the number of existing questions and answers.

If you ask and answer questions that haven't been asked or answered before you'll likely do well. Just as people did well in 2010 when they did the same. Then in 2030 you'll have as much rep from your answers as they did from theirs in the decade your answers were available.

Many other fields have new discoveries or proofs. I'm sure there are many questions that can't be answered yet because the groundwork to answer them does not exist. At some point they may become answerable and if you're the first person to do so you'll get the credit for that and help lots of people to boot.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't think about that